# Обращение к EndPoint устройства

Tags: c, c++-cli

Есть устройство (USB)
Если я работаю с устройством как с файлом(ReadFile, WriteFile)С++CLI, как обратиться и получить  значение из кейса, какую команду  и как отправить?

Код прошивки на С

```
#define  USB_REQ_TYPE_VENDOR                            0x40
#define  USB_REQ_TYPE_MASK                              0x60

static uint8_t  usbd_cdc_Setup (void  *pdev, 
                        USB_SETUP_REQ *req)
{
uint16_t len=USB_CDC_DESC_SIZ;
uint8_t  *pbuf=usbd_cdc_CfgDesc + 9;
uint8_t i;
switch (req->bmRequest & USB_REQ_TYPE_MASK)
{
case USB_REQ_TYPE_VENDOR:
{   
    memPrintNum = 0;
    switch(req->bRequest)
    {       
        case 0x26: //Head temp req
        {
            if( (req->wValue) == 0x00)
            {
                safeprintf(PUTCHAR_MEMORY,"%.1f",(float)printer.HeadTemp);
                safeputchar(PUTCHAR_MEMORY,0xf8);
                safeputchar(PUTCHAR_MEMORY,'C');
                USBD_CtlSendData (pdev, (uint8_t *)&printfText, 
memPrintNum);  
            }
            break;
        }   
        case 0x27: //power on counter
        {
            if( (req->wValue) == 0x00)
            {
                safeprintf(PUTCHAR_MEMORY,"%don",EEPROM_stat.powerOn);
                USBD_CtlSendData (pdev, (uint8_t *)&printfText, 
memPrintNum);  
            }
            break;
        }   

    }
}
 }
```

Comment: Устройства - USB?

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan да USB

Comment: Тогда явного способа выбрать конечную точку через Read/WriteFile не существует. Смотрите документацию на устройство, возможно драйвер, позволяет с помощью каких-от IO Control команд выбирать конечную точку или же в добавляет в систему дополнительные логические устройства для работы с другими конечными точками.

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan добавил код с прошивки который должен вернуть "Head temp req", я не совсем понимаю как к нему добраться, не подскажите, может конечная точка здесь не причем

Comment: Все от драйвера зависит. Какой вы используете?

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan usbprint.inf

Comment: А причём тут c++/cli? Вы уверены, что .то не чистый c++ или даже c?

Comment: @VladD я пишу софт на c++cli  который работает с устройством, а вставленный код это код с прошивки, а точнее данные которые мне нужно достать (сделать запрос и получить на него ответ)

Comment: @PabloMurena: Ну, в коде, который вы показали, нету ни капли cli и даже ни капли c++, так что я бы на вашем месте поставил другие теги.

Comment: @VladD поправил вопрос

Comment: Мне кажется что здесь нужно использовать IOCTL_USBPRINT_VENDOR_GET_COMMAND  я прав ?